# Javascript Sort by character appearance position

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    const input = 'hello world';
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sortAlphabets(input);

    function sortAlphabets(input) {
        return input.split('').sort().join('');
    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The result is: `dehllloorw`

But I want to change it to sort by character appearance position. The result should be: `hellloowrd`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a compare function with `.sort` and inside that function you can use `input.indexOf` to get the index of the first appearance of the character in the input string.

```js
input.split('').sort((a,b) => input.indexOf(a)-input.indexOf(b)).join('')
```

### EDIT

If you want spaces to be removed just use a filter after the split.

```js
input.split('').filter(c=>c!==' ').sort((a,b) => input.indexOf(a)-input.indexOf(b)).join('')
```

Comment: Add split and join finally so space will be removed

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom sort function, here will compare by index

```js
const input = 'hello world';

let splited = input.split('').map(e => e.trim());

let sorted = splited.sort((a, b) => {
  return splited.indexOf(a) - splited.indexOf(b);
}).join('');

console.log(sorted);
```