# How do I sort characters of a string by appearance order?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have the following code:

```
function main() {
  let input = prompt("Enter a string:").toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "");
  let process = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let word = input[i];
    let repeatWord = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
      repeatWord += word[j].repeat(j + 1);
    }
    process += repeatWord;
  }
  console.log(process);
}
```

How do I sort the characters of the string by order of first appearance?

For example, if I enter the string: `"Learning Center"`, then the expected result should be `"leeearrnnigct"`.

Comment: algorithm :
1. Create a map with the letters and their frequency in the given string.
for eg : L -> 1,  e -> 3, r -> 2 etc.

2. then traverse the string, if the element is found in the map, print it or add it that many times of frequency to answer the output string.

3. after printing, remove the key or letter from the map so that for next occurrence of letter you do not repeat above steps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Sort by character appearance position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537028/javascript-sort-by-character-appearance-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is yet another version. This one will keep blanks and distinguish between upper/lower case letters:

```js
const str="Learning Center".split(""),
  freq={};
str.forEach(c=>freq[c]=(freq[c]??0)+1);
const res=str.map(c=>{
 let s=c.repeat(freq[c]);
 freq[c]=0;
 return s
}).join("");

console.log(res);
```

If you prefer a case insensitive solution without blanks then simply modify it to:

```js
const str="Learning Center".toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","").split(""),
  freq={};
str.forEach(c=>freq[c]=(freq[c]??0)+1);
const res=str.map(c=>{
 let s=c.repeat(freq[c]);
 freq[c]=0;
 return s
}).join("");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store a counter of all the characters in your string. Then, since `Map` **preserves insertion order**, you can simply iterate through the counter and use each key’s value to regenerate the string via the String [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method and the Array [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.

```js
function appearanceSort(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "");

  const counter = new Map();
  for (const char of str) {
    if (counter.has(char)) {
      counter.set(char, counter.get(char) + 1);
    } else {
      counter.set(char, 1);
    }
  }

  const strArr = [];
  for (const [key, value] of counter) {
    strArr.push(key.repeat(value));
  }

  return strArr.join("");
}

console.log(appearanceSort("Learning Center")); // leeearrnnigct
```

However, the implementation above most likely won't work as expected with arbitrary unicode characters. To support [grapheme clusters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#utf-16_characters_unicode_code_points_and_grapheme_clusters), you can use a library such as [`grapheme-splitter`](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter), or the browser built-in [`Intl.Segmenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter), which looks like so:

```js
function appearanceSort(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "");

  const segments = Array.from(new Intl.Segmenter().segment(str)).map(({
    segment
  }) => segment);

  const counter = new Map();
  for (const char of segments) {
    if (counter.has(char)) {
      counter.set(char, counter.get(char) + 1);
    } else {
      counter.set(char, 1);
    }
  }

  const strArr = [];
  for (const [key, value] of counter) {
    strArr.push(key.repeat(value));
  }

  return strArr.join("");
}

console.log(appearanceSort("‍‍‍ Learning ‍‍‍ Center")); // ‍‍‍‍‍‍leeearrnnnigct
```

*Note*: `Intl.Segmenter` is currently **not supported** in Firefox. Use `"Segmenter" in Intl` to check for browser support and conditionally apply some fallback behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to create an array with all unique characters. Then iterate over it and count how many siblings each character has and then repeat the character as often as it appears.

```js
function main(input: string) {
    const arr = input.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/[ ]/g, '').split("");
    let uniqueLetters = [...new Set(arr)]
    let word = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < uniqueLetters.length; i++) {
        const letter = uniqueLetters[i];   
        const letterCount = arr.filter((l) => l == letter).length;
        word += letter.repeat(letterCount)
    }
    return word;
}

console.log(main("Learning Center")) // prints: leeearrnnnigct
```

Answer (score -1):

When you run through each characters in the string, create a new index and then use a third variable to swap the characters.

You can try the code below.

```
function suffle(target) {
  var chars = target.split("");
  var length = chars.length;

  for (var i = length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var tmp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[j];
    chars[j] = tmp;
  }

  return chars.join("");
}

console.log(suffle("hello"));
```

Comment: What's the complete code, sir? I'm still confused about it

Comment: i have updated the code to a function